# Jenkins - Slack Integration posts the wrong URL to our slack channel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack

Pretty much what the title says is what's going on.

Our Jenkins-Slack Integration is set up correctly to message our Slack channel with updates when builds from Jenkins run (either successfully or when it fails)

**Expected: http://[URLADDRESS]/job/[ProjectName]**

**Actual: http://[WRONGURL]/job/[ProjectName]**

Any clue as to why this is?

Comment: does Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL set correctly?

Comment: Well, that would explain it... I thought it had been, but it hadn't

Comment: great, i'll add an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL
```

Must be configure to the right url for the Slack Plugin to send the correct url.